# Query to show specific values from related tables

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

In my case i have three tables. The Contracts table, the agreements table and the payments table. What i have is a table with contracts which represents the value in debt, another table with the agreements of the conditions to pay off the debt, and another table related to the agreements table who has the debt split in parcels.

```
ContractsTable
(Id | Number |  Name  |    Debt   | ...)
 1  |  1234  | AAAAAA | 1250,00 € | ...
 2  |  1235  | BBBBBB | 5000,20 € | ...
 3  |  1236  | CCCCCC | 500,00 €  | ...

AgreementsTable
(Id | ContractId |    Debt   | IsValid | ...)
 1  |     1      | 1250,00 € |    1    | ...
 2  |     2      | 5000,20 € |    0    | ...
 3  |     2      | 5000,20 € |    1    | ...
 4  |     3      | 500,00 €  |    0    | ...

PaymentsTable
(Id  | AgreementId |    Date    |  Amount   | IsPaid | ...)
  1  |      1      | 01/08/2012 | 500,00 €  |   1    | ...
  2  |      1      | 01/09/2012 | 500,00 €  |   1    | ... -> Last payment
  3  |      1      | 01/10/2012 | 250,00 €  |   0    | ... -> Next Payment
  4  |      3      | 01/08/2012 | 1000,00 € |   1    | ...
  5  |      3      | 01/09/2012 | 1000,00 € |   1    | ...
  6  |      3      | 01/10/2012 | 1000,00 € |   0    | ...
  7  |      3      | 01/11/2012 | 1000,00 € |   0    | ...
  8  |      3      | 01/12/2012 | 1000,20 € |   0    | ...
```

So when i execute the stored procedure to get the table with the contracts, i want to somehow see a column with the date of last payment that was done and the date of next payment to be done too. But i will only be able to see the date of the last payment done and the date of the next payment to be done if the contract has a valid agreement related with and in the case of the next payment only if the agreement is valid.

I am working with MS Sql Server.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can you provide an example of the data and the results you want?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Will this work for you?

```
select aa.Id
        , aa.Number
        , aa.Name
        , aa.Debt
        ...
        , max(aa.Date_LastPayment) as Date_LastPayment
        , min(aa.Date_NextPayment) as Date_NextPayment
from    
(       
    select a.Id
            , a.Number
            , a.Name
            , a.Debt
            ...
            , case when c.IsPaid = 1 then c.[Date]
                    else null
                    end as Date_LastPayment
            , case when c.IsPaid = 0 then c.[Date]
                    else null
                    end as Date_NextPayment
    from ContractsTable a
    inner join AgreementsTable b on b.ContractId = a.Id
    inner join PaymentsTable c on c.AgreementId = b.Id
    where b.IsValid = 1
) aa
group by aa.Id
            , aa.Number
            , aa.Name
            , aa.Debt
            ...
```

I used 'min' for the **Next Payment Date** assuming there's multiple next payment dates.

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/d24eb/1)

Comment: It is almost what i need, the problem is because its showing all payment dates...

Comment: based on your sample data, what's your expected result?

Comment: And i need to get all the contracts who doens't have any agreement related at all. I am only getting the ones which have an active agreement. I am using MS Sql Server 2012 and as i said the query doesn't give the same results as the SQL Fiddle.

Comment: select a.Id ... from ContractsTable a where not exists (select 1 from AgreementsTable where ContractId = a.Id).

Comment: Thanks! Almost achieved what i need. Ok i discovered why he was showing all the payments. But i have to replace the `inner join agreements_table b on b.ContractId = a.Id` for `where not exists(select 1 from AgreementsTable where ContractId = a.Id)`? I tried and didn't work...

Comment: That query is for the contracts without any agreements at all. You can 'union' it to the query above.

Answer (score 0):

Max(PaymentsTable.Date) is not what you are looking for.
Please better define date of last payment and the date of next payment

```
select ContractsTable.Id,  ContractsTable.Number, ContractsTable.Debt 
, count(AgreementsTable.ID) as 'NumAgreements'
, max(PaymentsTable.Date) 
from ContractsTable 
left outter join AgreementsTable 
on ContractsTable.ID = AgreementsTable.ID 
left outter join PaymentsTable 
on ContractsTable.ID = PaymentsTable.ID
group by ContractsTable.Id,  ContractsTable.Number, ContractsTable.Debt
```